# Is there a simple solution to "exclude/hide" a div from a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make a onClick menu with jQuery and came up with a following problem:

There are 4 `<li>` elements containing a `<div>` inside, and I want to show that div when I click on selected `<li>`.
The `div` shows up, and when i click on other `li`, previously showed `div` hides and correct one, form clicked li, shows up. And that works fine, but when i click on that `div` the function again hides it and shows again, and thats what I'm trying to solve. I don't want that `<div>` to be taken under control by the function. In other words, when I click on that `div` I don't want anything to happen.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="footerMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>HOME<div class="onScreen"><img src="fillTxt.png"></div>></li>
            <li>PLENER<div class="onScreen"><img src="fillTxt2.png"></div></li>
            <li>STUDIO<div class="onScreen"><img src="fillTxt.png"></div></li>
            <li>INNE<div class="onScreen"> <img src="fillTxt2.png"></div></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("div.footerMenu li").click(
    function () {
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
        $(this).children("div.onScreen").fadeIn('fast');    
    },function(){
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
});//click
```

[The site](http://wujek-janek.com/fotozajac/) (lower left menu, HOME, PLENER etc. WARNING BIG PHOTOS)

Is there a simple solution to somehow "exclude/hide" that div from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (it intercepts the click from the `<div>` and prevents it from bubbling up and triggering the click on `<li>`)

```
$("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen").click( 
  function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false; } 
);
```

Comment: That works fine!! Everything just like I wanted. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

it is because the div is inside the "li" element...

```
$("div.footerMenu li").click(
    function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is("div.onScreen")) return;
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
        $(this).children("div.onScreen").fadeIn('fast');    
    },function(){
        if ($(event.target).is("div.onScreen")) return;
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
});
```

here you are asing, before performing any action, if you are not in the div layer, when clicked